# ImportError Scipy iOS

Tags: python, scipy, pip, homebrew

I have tried to install numpy, scipy and matplotlib using homebrew and pip install, the installation of numpy and matplotlib were succesfull and I can import them in python, but when I request to import scipy I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File      "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 118, in <module>
    from scipy._lib._ccallback import LowLevelCallable
  File     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/scipy/_lib/_ccallback.py", line 1, in <module>
  from . import _ccallback_c
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_ccallback_c.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/_lib/_ccallback_c.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

It is probably a problem with a Path but I can't find how to solve it.

Comment: Seems like the `scipy` you have loaded is not suitable for your computers architecture. Which OS do you use? I recommend using only one package manager. Try to uninstall homebrew and resinstall each package using `pip install pkg_name`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have OS El Capitan, 10.11.6. I uninstalled homebrew, installed pip installer and reinstalled scipy but get the same error. Any other idea?

Comment: There is a [similar question](/questions/10057095/installing-numpy-lion-with-python-2-7) on SO. Another option would be to uses [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos), which guarantees a fully functional scientific Python environment.

Comment: I also recommend to use Python3 (also Anaconda for Python3) since [Numpy plans to drop support for Python2.7 by 2020](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/neps/dropping-python2.7-proposal.rst).